# Android Camera2 gives up on AF lock

Tags: android, camera2, android-camera2

I'm testing my Camera2 implementation on Nexus 5 with 6.0.1. The problem seems to be related to switching flash modes. Quite unpredictably, changing the flash and taking a picture results in AF not locking and the following appearing in logs:

```
01-13 11:02:53.184   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.217   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.251   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.284   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.318   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.351   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.385   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.419   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.452   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.485   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.519   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.552   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.586   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.619   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:53.653   214  7175 I mm-camera: af_exhaustive_search: AEC not settled. Returning!
01-13 11:02:54.031   214  7174 I mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_process_aec_est:686 AEC EST DONE
01-13 11:02:54.031   214  7174 I mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_process_aec_est:686 AEC EST DONE
01-13 11:02:54.031   214  7174 I mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_process_aec_est:688 regular_led_trigger 1
01-13 11:02:54.648   804  1488 D NetlinkSocketObserver: NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=947757, 10.12.0.254, [000D483417C9], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_PROBE}
01-13 11:02:56.000   197   791 D audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
01-13 11:02:56.001   197   791 D audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
01-13 11:02:57.048   214  7192 E mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_upstream_module_event:1444 Reset previously set LED state!
01-13 11:02:57.048   214  7192 I AEC_PORT: aec_port_proc_downstream_event: Received LED state timeout. Reset LED state!
01-13 11:02:59.918   214  7175 E mm-camera: af_process_parse_stats: Invalid FV data!
01-13 11:02:59.918   214  7175 E mm-camera: af_process: Error processing AF stats!
01-13 11:02:59.952   214  7175 E mm-camera: af_process_parse_stats: Invalid FV data!
01-13 11:02:59.952   214  7175 E mm-camera: af_process: Error processing AF stats!
```

If I keep taking photos without switching flash modes, it works fine (even if the flash is always on). This happens only when I switch flash modes and it doesn't seem to matter which mode is active (so going from FLASH ON to FLASH AUTO or FLASH AUTO to FLASH OFF can both result in this error).

This is my code for changing flash modes:

```
private void setFlashMode(String mode) {
    if (mode.equals(CAMERA_FLASH_OFF) ) {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder
                .set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    }
    else if(mode.equals(CAMERA_FLASH_AUTO)) {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    }
    else if(mode.equals(CAMERA_FLASH_ON)) {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    }
    else if(mode.equals(CAMERA_FLASH_TORCH)) {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    }
    try {
        mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), null,
                mBackgroundHandler);
        if (getOnCameraParametersSetListener() != null) {
            getOnCameraParametersSetListener().onCameraParametersSet();
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,
                ".setFlashMode() - Exception caught while setting the capture session request",
                e);
    }
}
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was in not passing a callback when calling `setRepeatingRequest`. The fix was to add the original callback.